# How do I print the name of the field for a submission a value?

Tags: webforms

I have a custom webform confirmation page where I am print the submission values using the following:

```
<?php print $submission->data[67][0]; ?>
```

How can I print the title of the form field for the above data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Webform submission object's data parameter is a keyed array of component ID's/component submission data. The object doesn't contain the component field name so you'll need to reference its value through data attached on the node.

For example:

```
$webform_node = node_load($submission->nid);
foreach ($submission->data as $cid => $data) {
  print $webform_node->webform['components'][$cid]['name'] . ':' . $submission->data[$cid][0];
}
```